# C++ access violation crash

Tags: c++, access-violation

When I attempt to access this specific pointer, the application crashes and shows a c0000005 access violation error.

How can I catch this error and keep it from closing the process as I would in C# with a try&catch block.
Or how could I check if the access is denied to that area of memory before I use it?

Example:

```
MyClass** a = (MyClass**)(0x12345678);
a[0]->b = 1;
```

I am accessing a table of pointers and setting the value of one of the members of the class.
This does work, but the issue is that "0x12345678" doesn't always have the classes loaded in that area. The address has a value, but it doesn't point to the correct area of memory and it doesn't hold the value 0.

Keep in mind, this is a DLL that is loaded into a application that I no longer have the source for.
So I'm trying to set the settings of the application dynamically.

Comment: *So I'm trying to set the settings of the application dynamically.* Use Tools -> Options -> Settings rather than writing randomly into memory?

Comment: :T they are not options that I let the user change. This is basically a update to one of my old applications. Edit: I am not randomly writing into memory, I reversed the basic class structure that I used and I got the setting to change. The issue is simply that the setting class pointer sometimes holds a garbage value that points to an area that I don't have access to. @Seth Carnegie Then what would you recommend that does get the correct results.

Comment: You cannot do that as far as C++ is concerned.

Comment: @John oh, if this is reverse engineering then it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx) to trap these sorts of errors. In particular, filter for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.

Just make sure you know what you're doing when you swallow the exception: if your garbage address points to a guard page, you might see the behaviour described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. For that I provide to you all that I can offer. For the record I used __try and __except.